# chromedriver clicks are not registered, Element is not clickable at point

Tags: selenium, click, action, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am getting error while running tests on chromedriver where as it works fine on firefoxdriver:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not
>   clickable at point (1270, 449). Other element would receive the click:
>    (Session info: chrome=44.0.2403.157) (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.17.340124

I am trying to click a button and then click a list item from a dropdown menu. The button click is ok but the list item is not clicked even though it is there.

Any idea what's wrong? I am using latest chromedriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that the element is not fully loaded when you attempt to click it. Try using a FluentWait to wait for the element to appear/be clickable when clicking the dropdown and the button in the dropdown list for a quick debug.

Answer (score 1):

If you can see that it is not being blocked by another element. It could be because there is another transparent element over that element. Like a floating div with a fixed size a transparent image or how knows. It could also happen that the element is partially covered by another, and since selenium clicks on the center of the element, it could be detecting that case.

Comment: Yes there was a loading graphics on the page, I inserted some delay and now the clicks works

Comment: I can't comment on the accepted answer yet. So I'll put this here. I understand that the diagnosis of the problem is more accurate, but the solution is not the ideal. The use of Thread.sleep is a very bad practice while developing Selenium automatization. Its best to use FluentWaits.

Comment: Make sense.. I have just used this sleep for debugging and I am yet to find a best solution to handle the "loading grapchics div" on my page.